# Classpath resource gets duplicated by (probably) sbt

Tags: android, scala, sbt

I'm trying to setup simple Android project in Scala and Akka using sbt and [jberkel/android-plugin](https://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin). I successfully managed to create simple application based on [getting started tutorial of android-plugin](https://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin/wiki/getting-started). I also managed to assemble ProGuard configuration which enabled me to mix Akka into the project.

Now I want to add Akka configuration file and I am unable to do it. I created it in `src/main/resources` folder and expected it to just work. Unfortunately, during APK assembly, sbt fails with following error:

```
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last Akkdroid/android:package-debug for the full output.
[error] (Akkdroid/android:package-debug) 
[error] Using keystore: /home/ghik/.android/debug.keystore
[error] Packaging akkdroid-0.1.apk
[error] /data/Studia/S10/Mobilne/akkdroid/target/resources.apk:
[error] => res/layout/main.xml
[error] => AndroidManifest.xml
[error] => resources.arsc
[error] /data/Studia/S10/Mobilne/akkdroid/target/classes.dex => classes.dex
[error] /data/Studia/S10/Mobilne/akkdroid/target/classes.min.jar:
[error] => akkdroid.conf
[error] => library.properties
[error] => reference.conf
[error] => org/jboss/netty/container/spring/beans.xml
[error] /data/Studia/S10/Mobilne/akkdroid/src/main/resources/akkdroid.conf => akkdroid.conf
[error] 
[error] Error packaging /data/Studia/S10/Mobilne/akkdroid/target/akkdroid-0.1.apk: Duplicate files at the same path inside the APK
[error] Total time: 20 s, completed 2013-04-24 20:32:47
```

From these messages, I'm deducing that my `akkdroid.conf` file is at first copied (by ProGuard?) into `classes.min.jar` and later `sbt` tries to build the package including resources from both `classes.min.jar` and `src/main/resources` and it ends up seeing my file twice.

Unfortunately I have no idea why this happens and how to fix it.

If it helps, here's my `sbt` buildfile (mostly generated from [jberkel's template](https://github.com/jberkel/android-app.g8)):

```
import sbt._

import Keys._
import AndroidKeys._

object General {
  val settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
    name := "Akkdroid",
    version := "0.1",
    versionCode := 0,
    scalaVersion := "2.10.1",
    platformName in Android := "android-10",
    javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.6", "-target", "1.6")
  )

  val proguardSettings = Seq(
    useProguard in Android := true,
    proguardOption in Android :=
      """-keepclassmembers class * {
        |  ** MODULE$;
        | }
        |-keep public class akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider {
        |public <init>(...);
        |}
        |-keep public class akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider {
        |public <init>(...);
        |}
        |-keep class akka.actor.SerializedActorRef {
        |*;
        |}
        |-keep class akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport {
        |*;
        |}
        |-keep class akka.serialization.JavaSerializer {
        |*;
        |}
        |-keep class akka.serialization.ProtobufSerializer {
        |*;
        |}
        |-keep class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage {
        |*;
        |}
        |-keep class akka.event.Logging*
        |-keep class akka.event.Logging$LogExt{
        |*;
        |}
        |-keep class scala.Option
        |-keep class scala.Function1
        |-keep class scala.PartialFunction
        |-keep class scala.collection.SeqLike {
        |public protected *;
        |}
        |-keep class akka.**
        |-keepclassmembers class akka.**
        |-keep class org.omg.**
        |-keep class scala.Tuple2
        |-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
        |-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
      """.stripMargin
  )

  lazy val fullAndroidSettings =
    General.settings ++
      AndroidProject.androidSettings ++
      TypedResources.settings ++
      proguardSettings ++
      AndroidManifestGenerator.settings ++
      AndroidMarketPublish.settings ++ Seq(
      keyalias in Android := "change-me",
      libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "1.9.1" % "test"
    )
}

object AndroidBuild extends Build {
  javacOptions ++= Seq("-target", "1.6")

  lazy val main = Project(
    "Akkdroid",
    file("."),
    settings = General.fullAndroidSettings ++ Seq(
      libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.10" % "2.1.2",
      libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-remote_2.10" % "2.1.2"
    )
  )

  lazy val tests = Project(
    "tests",
    file("tests"),
    settings = General.settings ++
      AndroidTest.androidSettings ++
      General.proguardSettings ++ Seq(
      name := "AkkdroidTests"
    )
  ) dependsOn main
}
```

I would be very grateful for some help. I have almost no experience in Android or SBT.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem.  I don't know if this is the best way to deal with it, but I put my configuration file in the android project's `raw` directory.  Then I parse it into a [`Config`](http://typesafehub.github.io/config/latest/api/index.html?com/typesafe/config/Config.html) object and pass it to the `ActorSystem` constructor.

```
object AkkaSystem {
  private var systemOption: Option[ActorSystem] = None

  def system(implicit context: Context): ActorSystem = synchronized {
    systemOption match {
      case None =>
        val reader = new InputStreamReader(
          context.getResources.openRawResource(R.raw.configuration)
        )
        systemOption = Option (
          ActorSystem("MySystem", ConfigFactory.parseReader(reader))
        )
        reader.close()
        systemOption.get
      case Some(existingSystem) => existingSystem
    }
  }
}
```

Then in my `Activity` class I can use that `AkkaSystem` object to get the configured `ActorSystem`:

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {
  implicit val context = this

  private def mainActor = AkkaSystem.system.actorOf(Props[MainActor], "main")
}
```

I agree that it would be better if I could avoid all that code and the need to pass the `Context` in order to get at the Android resource.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way that seems to work, and avoids to the need to use the Android `Context` to load the Akka configuration as a raw android resource.  I'm not sure it's more "correct" than treating the configuration file as a raw Android resource.

I created a directory named `config` at the top level of my `sbt` project, and I put my Akka configuration file, named `application.conf`, into that directory.

```
myapp/
    config/
        application.conf
    project/
        Build.scala
        plugins.sbt
    src/
        main/
            scala/
```

Then I added the following setting to my Build.scala:

```
unmanagedClasspath in Runtime <+= (baseDirectory) map { bd => Attributed.blank(bd / "config") }
```

I'm using [Jan Berkel's Android application template](https://github.com/jberkel/android-app.g8), whence originated my `Build.scala`.  The relevant setting in context looks like

```
object General {
  val settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq (
    name := "AkkaWeb",
    version := "0.1",
    <other settings elided>...
    unmanagedClasspath in Runtime <+= (baseDirectory) map { bd => Attributed.blank(bd / "config") }
)
```

I had to do an sbt `clean` as well as `reload`, but after that the `application.conf` file shows up in the `.apk` file along with Akka's default `reference.conf` file, and Akka reads it when I construct an `ActorSystem`.

One point worth noting: if I construct the `ActorSystem` in my main thread, then reading the configuration file causes a disk access violation when running in [strict mode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html).  This is a separate problem that is off-topic for this question, but something to be aware of, particularly as I can see a noticeable delay when constructing an `ActorSystem`.

This solution is copied directly from the Akka documentation [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Classpaths.html#example), where you can read further details to understand what exactly it's doing.

### Update

I just noticed something else.  The order of maven artifacts in my `Build.scala` affects which `reference.conf` appears in the `.apk` file.  I have to put `akka-actor` before other artifacts that have `reference.conf` files to be used with the Typesafe config library if I want the `reference.conf` from the `akka-actor` jar to be the one that appears as `reference.conf` in my `.apk` file.  For example:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.10" % "2.1.4",
    "io.spray" % "spray-util" % "1.1-M7.1-openssl-M6"
)
```

If the order of these two artifacts is reversed, then the `reference.conf` file in the resulting `.apk` file will be the one from the Spray artifact rather than the Akka artifact.